# How to return the array in my method?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I have a method as below in the `Task` class. It is as follows:

```
public void populateJTable(){
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++){
           String name = tasks.get(i).getTaskName();
           String dueDate = tasks.get(i).getTaskPriority();
           String priority = tasks.get(i).getTaskPriority();

           Object[] data = {name, dueDate, priority}; //would like to return this
    }}
```

I would like to return the `Object [] data ...` from the method so that I can add it to my JTable in my `GUI` class. How would i do this. My `GUI` class is below:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Task", "Due Date", "Priority"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
table = new JTable(tableModel);
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
tableModel.add(data); // would like to add the data here from the populateJTable method.
```

Thanks.

Comment: What `Task` class do you mean? Afaik there's none in swing and from the method name it looks to be a custom class so what's the problem with just changing the return type? Besides that you might also think about passing a reference to the table model to that method and add the data there.

Answer (score 1):

Just redefine your method as follows:

```
public Object[] pupulateJTable() {
    ....
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then it asks me to initialise the variable.

Comment: Then data isn't initialized before you attempt to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of your method from `void` to `Object[]` and add `return data;` at the end of your method.

Comment: I tried that but then it asks me to initialise the variable.

Comment: That&#39;s because it should be `Object[] data = new Object[]{/*whatever here*/};`

Answer (score 0):

> would like to return this

then change the return type of the method, that can not be void since void returns nothing... you need something like:

```
public Object[] pupulateJTable() {
    // TODDY....
    return new Object[]{name, dueDate, priority}; 
}
```

Comment: It is still asking me to add a return type.

Comment: impossible bro, you have this: **return new Object[]{name, dueDate, priority};**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on tasks.size() you can have many task names, dates and priorities. I would suggest to return a `List<String[]>` instead. Example:

```
public List<String[]> populateJTable(){
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++){
           String name = tasks.get(i).getTaskName();
           String dueDate = tasks.get(i).getTaskPriority();
           String priority = tasks.get(i).getTaskPriority();

           list.add(new String[]{name, dueDate, priority}); 
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Looking at this for a second time this dosen't make no sence. Why don't you just access your tasks variable or return tasks?